# Potential problems with installing Ubuntu on a Lenovo Ideacentre 300 desktop?

Tags: system-installation, lenovo, hardware, compatibility

I'm planning to wipe the drive and install Ubuntu on an inexpensive [Lenovo Ideacentre 300](http://shop.lenovo.com/us/en/desktops/ideacentre/300-series/300/) desktop computer. Can anyone foresee any issues or problems?

Comment: Lenovo 300 has 6 different base hardware configurations plus several upgrades to each one. Please edit and add your hardware specifications.